# How to run linux command in python console

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run linux command like `ls`, `pwd`,etc. directly in python console but failed.

```
#python3
>ls
>pwd
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: @IainShelvington derek is asking how to run a linux command from a *python shell*, not from a *python script*.